# (ES6) Data from JSON to HTML (div's)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have this JSON File:

```
{
 "clubs":  [
{
  "name": "Feyenoord Rotterdam",
  "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
  "championships": "15"

},

{
  "name": "Sparta Rotterdam",
  "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
  "championships": "6"
},

{
  "name": "AZ Alkmaar",
  "origin": "Noord-Holland",
  "championships": "2"
},

{
  "name": "Willem II",
  "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
  "championships": "3"
},

{
  "name": "PSV Eindhoven",
  "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
  "championships": "24"

}
]
}
```

I want to put the data (name, origin, championships) from every club in a separate div. I'm trying to do that with ES6.
This is my code right now:

```
{

    const createDiv = clubs => {
    const $div = document.createElement(`div`);
    $div.classList.add(`club-info`);
    document.querySelector(`.clubs`).appendChild($div);

    const $club = document.createElement(`p`);
    $club.classList.add(`.clubname`);
    $club.textContent = `${clubs.name}`;

    const $origin = document.createElement(`p`);
    $origin.classList.add(`.origin`);
    $origin.textContent = `${clubs.origin}`;

    const $championships = document.createElement(`p`);
    $championships.classList.add(`.championships`);
    $championships.textContent = `${clubs.championships}`;


    document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($club);
    document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($origin);
    document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($championships);
  };

  const makeDivs = clubs => {
   clubs.forEach(club => {
      createDiv(club);
    });
};

const parse = clubs => {
  makeDivs(clubs);
};

  const init = () => {
    const url = `./assets/data/data.json`;

    fetch(url)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(json => parse(json.clubs));
  };
  init();

}
```

The problem now is that I have 5 different divs with the class "club-info", but that all the data goes to the first div as you can see in the picture.

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZpE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($club);
document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($origin);
document.querySelector(`.club-info`).appendChild($championships);
```

, it looks up the first `.club-info` element each time. It doesn't know that you want to use the element also stored in `$div`.

Since `$div` contains your current `.club-info` element, you can use that variable instead:

```
$div.appendChild($club);
$div.appendChild($origin);
$div.appendChild($championships);
```